# Difference on marshmallow between ModelSerializer(model) and ModelSerializer().dump(model)

Tags: python, json, orm, marshmallow

I'm using marshmallow to serialize my objects to JSON and just realized that the output in `ModelSerializer(model).data` is equal to `ModelSerializer().dump(model).data`

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelSerializer(model).data` is deprecated API. Use `ModelSerializer().dump(model).data` instead.

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrading.html#module-marshmallow

In version 2.0, the legacy API will be completely removed.